# Create New WordPress User after Twitter Signin, using Twitter credentials?

Tags: twitter

I've seen wp-snippets.com uses Twitter sign-in which somehow creates a WordPress users with the Twitter credentials.

wp-snippets.com > signin with twitter > Oauth > CallbackURL = wp-admin with twitter credentials written to WP user

How is this achieved? I've searched a lot plugins and cannot see anything that writes twitter user details to the Wordpress database. I expect if any that the Otto's Simple Twitter Connect (STC) might have, but I'vve installed and examined it; I cannot see this feature anyway.

Comment: I don't know if this has been resolved yet but how about when you click auth you ask te user for email during process or it won't continue?

Answer (score 3):

I have done that before by using the Gigya Socialize plugin

check it out
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/gigya-socialize-for-wordpress/

Answer (score 3):

STC does not have a signup/register function, because Twitter doesn't provide any API to get an email for the user. So the signup process has no way to email the user with valid information like password and such.

If you have a better way/workflow/design/idea to do it, then I'd be happy to add it to Simple Twitter Connect.

Comment: Hey Otto! I have no idea about the techs involved. I'd just seen it done on another site (wp-snippets.com) so was wondering how they achieved it. I saw in the source code that they were using TwitConnect plugin, so I checked that out and it does indeed create a new WordPress user. They create a dummy email address (email@[twitter_api_domain]) and append a suffix to the username so-as not to conflict with standard WordPress users.

Comment: Yeah, I rejected that approach immediately. Creating a fake user with a fake email address is not something I'd want in my database, so I can't see why anybody else would want that either. Fake users are fake, and useless.